# Array at index returning undefined in Angular ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using Angular 7 and .NET Core 2.2, I'm working on a financial application and a watchlist for it. Symbols are added (and saved to a database). When the watchlist component loads, in `ngOnInit`, I get the data pulled from my resolver via router. Then I call a function which takes an array, loops through them, and returns a different data set from the financial data source. I then push each one of those returned items from the Observable into a local array `watchListItems: IEXStockPrice[];`

My code is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.watchListItemsFromDb = data['watchListItems'];
      if (this.watchListItemsFromDb) {
        this.fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX(this.watchListItemsFromDb);
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.watchListItems);
    console.log(this.watchListItems[0]);
  }

  fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX(items: WatchListItemFromNet[]) {
    if (!this.watchListItems) {
      this.watchListItems = [];
    }

    items.forEach(element => {
      this.iex.getStockQuoteBySymbol(element.symbol)
        .subscribe(
          (iexData: IEXStockPrice) => {
            this.watchListItems.push(iexData);
          },
          (err: any) => this.alertify.error('Could not get the latest data from IEX.')
        );
    });
  }
```

Now, I have a child component `LineChartComponent` which needs to create a line chart/graph of the active watchlist item. I was just going to first load the chart component with the first element in the `watchListItems` array. I can't get access to it in `ngOnInit` because the component hasn't finished initializing.

I've tried ngAfterViewInit.

However, as you can see in the picture, the watchListItems has content in it, but trying to access the first element returns `undefined`.

[image]

Comment: The router data is async. You would need to call `this.fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX(this.watchListItemsFromDb);` only if`this.watchListItemsFromDb` is truthy

Comment: this.router.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.watchListItemsFromDb = data['watchListItems']; this.fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX(this.watchListItemsFromDb);
    });

Answer (score 0):

Since the router provides its data as an Observable, I would only call `fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX()` if `watchListItemsFromDb` has been populated

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.watchListItemsFromDb = data['watchListItems'];

      if (this.watchListItemsFromDb) {
          this.fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX(this.watchListItemsFromDb);
      }
    });
}

fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX(items: WatchListItemFromNet[]) {

    // initialize your array here vs in the viewmodel
    if (!this.watchListItems) {
        this.watchListItems = [];
    }

    items.forEach(element => {
      this.iex.getStockBySymbol(element.symbol)
        .subscribe(
          (iexData: IEXStockPrice) => {
            this.watchListItems.push(iexData);
          },
          (err: any) => this.alertify.error('Could not load watchlist')
        );
    });
  }
```

Then in your component, you can check for the array, then pass the first item to your child component as an @Input:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="watchListItemsFromDb">
  <child-component [data]="watchListItemsFromDb[0]"></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I tried this. console logging watchListItems[0] still returns undefined.

Comment: Hmm. Let me get a StackBlitz going to help.

Comment: It's always going to return truthy because I initialize watchListItems to an empty array at the top of the component.

Comment: Ah. In that case, it should work if you don't pre-initialize the array.

Comment: Hm. doesn't seem to. I have to initialize it somewhere before the subscribe because I can't "push" anything into an uninitialized array.

Comment: You can do that in the `fetchLatestPriceforWatchListItemsFromIEX` function. I added some code the example.

Comment: Alternatively, you could check the length of the array is > 0 in the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: see my updated code in the main question. It's still coming back undefined. Checking the length of watchlistItems always returns 0 even though there are clearly 5 elements in it.

Comment: This is because by of the async call to get the router data. What are you needing to do in the AfterViewInit() ?

Comment: all I need to do is access the first element (and really only the symbol) in the watchListItems array and pass that to the child component so it can graph the series but, like I said. WatchListItems[0] is continuously undefined.

Comment: I would pass the data to the child component as an @Input. You can wrap the child component in an if statement that checks for the presence of the array first, then passes the first item in the array as the data.